# Setup SSL in azure application gateway

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-application-gateway

I setup an application gateway at Azure with two VMs. Now, I'm trying to install a SSL certificate into one domain name.

I upload the .cer file and I received a message that this certificate has been installed. But when I try to access the website with https, nothing happens.

Is there a step by step to install a certificate at Azure Application Gateway? Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: If the reply is helpful or you need further help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you should upload a .pfx file certificate. Click HTTPS for the protocol of the listener and make sure that the port is defined as 443.

Use the command to export a .pfx certificate.

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Azure123456!" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate \
  -cert cert:\localMachine\my\E1E81C23B3AD33F9B4D1717B20AB65DBB91AC630 \
  -FilePath c:\appgwcert.pfx \
  -Password $pwd
```

You can get more details from this guide: [Configure an application gateway with SSL termination using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-ssl-portal)

Hope this helps.